# Exporting Multiple Groups' members into one csv file

Tags: powershell

Need your assistance again. This time in creating a script to export all members of for multiple sec-groups into one csv file.

Like this:

```
UserName    UserID      Sec Group
user1               Group 1
User2               Group 1
User3               Group 1
User3               Group 2
User4               Group 1
User4               Group 2
User4               Group 3
```

This is my current script for getting the members of just one group using my PS a form.

```
$ExportMembers.Add_Click(
    {
        $export = "C:\Users\crondon\Documents\TOOL\$($groupname.Text).txt"

        $actualgrp = (get-adgroup -filter "name -eq '$($groupname.Text)'").SamAccountName

        $groups = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $actualgrp | select name, samaccountname | Sort name | 
        Out-String -width 700

        $groups>> $export

        $content = Get-Content $export

        $content | Foreach { $_.TrimEnd() } | Set-Content $export

        $Output.text = "$($groupname) members have been exported!!"

        Get-ADGroupMember -identity $actualgrp | select name, samaccountname | Export-csv 
        "C:\Users\crondon\Documents\TOOL\$($groupname.Text).csv" -append
    }
)
```

Also, I noticed that there seems to be a limitation on how many members a group has that Powershell can export. Is there a way around it?

Thanks!!

Comment: To create CSV files remove `Out-String -width 700` and instead use `Export-Csv -Path $export -NoTypeInformation`. If you need to import that data again use `Import-Csv`

Comment: gotcha. How  about the excel export information? Would like it to show the name of each the group along with the name/ID of each users by row

Comment: You would need a loop then and for each of the group members output an object with the desired properties. Remember that `Get-ADGroupMember` can also return members of type group and computer, not just users so I would advise to also add a property `ObjectClass` to each of the output objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comments; here's your updated code for the click handler.

```
$ExportMembers.Add_Click(
    {
        $group     = $groupname.Text
        $actualgrp = Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -eq '$group'"
        if ($actualgrp) {
            # because this could take some time, show the user the code is busy
            $Output.Text = "Gathering members of group '$group'.."

            $export  = "C:\Users\crondon\Documents\TOOL\$group.csv"
            # get all members of this group and export to csv
            $members = $actualgrp | Get-ADGroupMember | ForEach-Object {
                [PsCustomObject]@{
                    Group          = $group
                    Name           = $_.Name
                    SamAccountName = $_.SamAccountname
                    Type           = $_.objectClass       # user, group or computer
                }
            }
            $members | Sort-Object Name | Export-Csv -Path $export -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
            # show success message
            $Output.Text = "$group members have been exported!!"
        }
        else {
            # show failure message
            $Output.Text = "Group '$group' does not exist.."
        }
    }
)
```

<sup>P.S. I have used switch `-UseCulture` on the Export-Csv handler. This will ensure the file is written in such a way that you can simply double-click the csv file later to open in Excel.</sup>